# Using Google Earth as view with SQL Server or Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, sql-server, google-earth

How do I connect Google Earth with any relation database? I have **live database** containing **spatial** co-ordinates i.e latitude and longitude. User should be able to view these live data on google earth.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Is it retrieving your data from database and then viewing on Google Earth or something else?

Comment: @thelastray yes only viewing. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to serve the data as static KML, the easiest option is to use [ST_AsKML](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsKML.html) function in PostGIS. However if you want to use live KML data, one option could be using GeoServer and get the output in [KML format](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/googleearth/quickstart.html#direct-access-to-kml).

Comment: I added Network Link but could not see any points should I use SLD? I already have SLD for wms layer

Comment: Try to add your layer in Openlayers as WFS and check whether it is working. There may be problem in your GEOSERVER_URL. For styling check [KML Styling](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/googleearth/kmlstyling.html#kml-styling)

Comment: Geoserver for the Open Source - or if have a good budget FME Server with Network KML/Z streaming service is excellent.